# apache zeppelin additional repository import

Tags: java, scala, maven, apache-zeppelin, saddle

How to import an additional dependency in zeppelin?

I am trying to import a library (saddle) in apache zeppelin, however ...

```
import org.saddle._

<console>:21: error: object saddle is not a member of package org
   import org.saddle._
              ^
```

I've tried using the %dep interpreter (dependency loader) like this:

```
%dep
z.reset()
z.addRepo("Saddle Repo").url("http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scala-saddle/saddle_2.10/1.0.1")
z.load("org.scala-saddle:saddle_2.10:1.3.0")
```

I've also tried in the GUI by 1. including the maven repository under interpreter dependencies, or 2. including the saddle website under zeppelin.dep.additionalRemoteRepository.

I've also tried downloading the jar file and including it in conf/zeppelin-env.sh as SPARK_SUBMIT_OPTIONS.

I've then copied the jar to zeppelin-zengine/target/lib/, when I saw jars from there where used and imported.

So far, I haven't made it work. Help appreciated.

Comment: have you restarted the spark interpreter, and re-run the %dep paragraph?

Comment: Yes. I have tried both options of shutting down the notebook server and restarting the interpreter from inside the GUI.

Comment: Could the host where Zeppelin is started connect to mvnrepository.com? I think it might not be able to connect to that site

Comment: I don't have any issues with my internet connection. When I use %dep I just get deprecated warnings and "res0: org.apache.zeppelin.dep.Dependency = org.apache.zeppelin.dep.Dependency@246390b2"

Comment: Even if I load from my file system, it doesn't work; z.load("/path/to.jar")

Comment: what is the type of your master? yarn? standalone?

Comment: Standalone. I just use the bin/zeppelin.sh script to start up.

Comment: just as last gasp, could you try add your jar to /ZEPPELIN_HOME/lib and then restat zepplein?

Comment: which one do you mean? ./spark/target/lib
./zeppelin-display/target/lib
./zeppelin-interpreter/target/lib
./zeppelin-server/target/lib
./zeppelin-zengine/target/lib

Comment: I could see that you have build zeppelin yourself, and didn't use the binary distribution. so I think it is in ./spark/target/lib

Comment: Were you able to make progress...I am on same boat ?? any help is appreciated

Comment: Unfortunately, no.

Answer (score 1):

I am sure that you must solved the problem by now. Posting it if somebody else facing the issue. I tried the following and it worked. There is no need to add maven as it is already added to Zeppelin.

```
%spark.dep
z.load("org.scala-saddle:saddle-core_2.11:1.3.4")
```

Answer (score 0):

Interpreter Repository config GUI in Zeppelin. com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory or Saddle Core » 1.3.4

error: object typesafe is not a member of package com

1 - Open site https://mvnrepository.com/  and find "saddle" repository.

SCALA Version, then click on Buildr

[image]

## https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scala-saddle/saddle-core

'org.scala-saddle:saddle-core_2.11:jar:1.3.4'

2 - Click on “Anonymous” at the top right, a drop down menu will pop up, click on “Interpreters”, then at the new page search or scroll down to “Spark”. In the top right of the Spark interpreter tile there are three buttons, “Edit”, “Restart”, “Remove”. Click “Edit” then You will see Dependencies and Values. Scroll down and find the property and click ADD and complete properties:

[image]

And click Save.

3- Test

[image]