# How to Add Additional Remote Repository to Zeppelin?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-zeppelin

Using the following code in a Zepplin note, I was able to add a repository and dependency. How would I accomplish the same using `zeppelin.dep.additionalRemoteRepository`?

```
%dep

z.addRepo("hortonworks").url("http://repo.hortonworks.com/content/repositories/releases")
z.load("com.hortonworks:shc-core:1.1.1-2.1-s_2.11")
```

I tried, but failed with:

```
spark-packages,
http://dl.bintray.com/spark-packages/maven,
false;hortonworks,http://repo.hortonworks.com/content/repositories/releases,false;
```

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36750057/apache-zeppelin-additional-repository-import