# Zeppelin does not load maven jar

Tags: maven, apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

Apache Zeppelin Version 0.7.1

```
%dep
z.reset() // clean up previously added artifact and repository

// add maven repository
z.addRepo("Spark Cassandra Connector 2.0.10").url("https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.datastax.spark/spark-cassandra-connector")

// add artifact recursively
// z.load("groupId:artifactId:version")
z.load("com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector_2.11:2.0.10") 

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:352)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.dep.SparkDependencyContext.fetchArtifactWithDep(SparkDependencyContext.java:171)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.dep.SparkDependencyContext.fetch(SparkDependencyContext.java:121)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.DepInterpreter.interpret(DepInterpreter.java:245)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.LazyOpenInterpreter.interpret(LazyOpenInterpreter.java:95)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterServer$InterpretJob.jobRun(RemoteInterpreterServer.java:490)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.Job.run(Job.java:175)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.FIFOScheduler$1.run(FIFOScheduler.java:139)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

The following doesn't seem to be helpful:

1. [apache zeppelin additional repository import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36750057/apache-zeppelin-additional-repository-import)
2. In https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.7.1/interpreter/spark.html, it gives an example of setting `zeppelin.dep.additionalRemoteRepository` to `http://dl.bintray.com/spark-packages/maven`, but this repo doesn't have the version of jar I need.
3. https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.7.1/interpreter/spark.html#3-dynamic-dependency-loading-via-sparkdep-interpreter
4. [Zeppelin dynamic dependency loading fails on os-maven-plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59425963/zeppelin-dynamic-dependency-loading-fails-on-os-maven-plugin)

---

Now I'm getting

```
%dep
z.load("com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector_2.11:2.0.10")

org.sonatype.aether.resolution.DependencyResolutionException: Could not find artifact com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector_2.11:jar:2.0.10 in central (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/)
```

Comment: may I ask why 0.7.1? It's very old....

Comment: customer doesn't want to upgrade, so we continue to support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I need to update the maven reposition url from `http` to `https` in `zeppelin-env.sh`

```
export ZEPPELIN_INTERPRETER_DEP_MVNREPO="https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/"
```

There are also other non-generic changes specific to our build system (Jenkins pipeline)

If you have control over the server, it would be much easier to just download the jar you need (i.e. `"groupArtifactVersion": "com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector_2.11:2.0.10",`), then load the dependency from disk, like:

```
%dep
z.load("/opt/zeppelin/spark-cassandra-connector-assembly/spark-cassandra-connector-assembly.jar")
```

Comment: here is what worked for me: export ZEPPELIN_INTERPRETER_DEP_MVNREPO="https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2"